# Excel Weekday function, finding day in week

Tags: excel, weekday

I have a sheet with some dates, and to find Mondays, Tuesdays and Thursdays I use this code

```
=HVIS.FEJL(SAMMENLIGN(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;-2)-UGEDAG(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;3))+AG5*7;Året!$B$6:$B$40;0);"")
```

It will find the Mondays, and works fine - when I look at the Tuesdays and Thursdays I changes the first number in "UGEDAG"..;1; to 0 for Thursdays or -2 for Tuesdays, I was trying some numbers step by step, and end up with these numbers, can someone tell me why:
1 = Monday (i think I know why) but, -2 = Tuesday and 0 = Thursday

Can someone explain to me why these numbers?
Hvis.Fejl is If.Error, Sammenlign is Match, Ugedag is Weekday and År is Year.

[image]

Comment: So far I've figured out that you are trying to determine the last Monday of the prior year using this:
=DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;-2)-UGEDAG(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;3))

I have no idea what is in AG5, but if it is a whole number, it will still result in a Monday when added to the above.

Thus, I think you are asking why the value in the second part needs to be adjusted to 0 for Thursdays and -2 for Tuesdays.  I hope I am understanding.

Comment: You are understanding that right and the AG5 is a weeknumber integer.
And yes it's the part about 1, 0 and -2 i'm asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the additional detail but I will probably never fully understand what the sheet is doing.  What I think is happening is that since December 29, 2017 is a Friday, the computation you are doing chooses days between 12/22 (Friday) and 12/28 (Thursday).  In other words the formula DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;-2) will artificially make Friday the first day of the week.  Had these been days in 2017, we would see this problem starting on Thursdays (Sunday through Wednesday would be in one week and Thursday through Saturday would be in another).  This could be because of how you define WEEKNUM (UGE.NR) since there is a parameter to tell it what day of the week to use, but I suspect the problem comes from choosing the 29th of December of the prior year.  I think you want to settle on a specific day of the week at the end of the year and then compute from there.

Without knowing more, I think we should change this computation:

```
=HVIS.FEJL(SAMMENLIGN(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;-2)-UGEDAG(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;3))+AG5*7;Året!$B$6:$B$40;0);"")
```

I think it is not doing what you need.  I think this will give the same result for Mondays:

```
=HVIS.FEJL(SAMMENLIGN(HELTAL(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;-2)/7)*7+2+AG5*7;Året!$B$6:$B$40;0);"")
```

Where HELTAL(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;-2)/7)*7 gives you the Saturday in the last full week in the prior year (I think HELTAL is INT) and we add 2 to get to Monday.  This seems a little more straightforward to follow since changing the "+2" to "+3" would give you Tuesday:

```
=HVIS.FEJL(SAMMENLIGN(HELTAL(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;-2)/7)*7+3+AG5*7;Året!$B$6:$B$40;0);"")
```

Changing it to "+5" would give you Thursday

```
=HVIS.FEJL(SAMMENLIGN(HELTAL(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;-2)/7)*7+5+AG5*7;Året!$B$6:$B$40;0);"")
```

Since we are beginning on a Sunday, I do not think you will see the problems you are seeing using the existing formulas for Fridays(+6) or Saturdays(+7).

You may need to adjust the formula a bit, but I think this will get you closer to what you need.

Comment: Okay and +1 is Sunday :-)
My weeks the first day is Monday, and not Sunday, but this works - and better than the other... thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening here in the original formula is this:

1. Whatever date is in B2 we are taking the prior 12/29
2. Then, we will use this information to determine the previous Monday

The WEEKDAY function gives the each day of the week a number starting with Sunday.  Essentially, this can be thought of as the number of days after Saturday.  So subtracting this offset from Saturday from always will always bring us back to the first Saturday of the week.

This formula: WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Sheet1!$B$2),1,3)) or more accurately, your UGEDAG(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;3)), is asking what day of the week the 3rd of January is for a year in Cell B2 of that sheet and it is then being used to determine the Monday prior to the 29th of the prior year.  In other words, it is asking the offset from Saturday for the 3rd day of the year and is using this starting point to determine the earlier Monday.  To use this for Tuesday or Thursday, what might make more sense would be varying the day (i.e. the 3) rather than the month (i.e. the 1).  To get Mondays, use 3.  To get Tuesdays, you would use 2 (going forward a day from Monday, you would subtract a day less).  Since days of the week are Mod 7, to get Thursdays, you would go back two more days and use 0 (or more likely 7 since day 0 of any month does not always seem like it makes logical sense).

What you were seeing is that if you vary the month as you describe, it works similarly, especially since you are limiting it to December of the prior year (Month 0), January of the current year (Month 1), and October of the prior year (Month -2).  The reason is that the 3rd day of the month for those months are related in the same way as my days of the week and you never cross a February which does not always have the same number of days.

In other words, I use an offset of 3 to compute my Mondays, I use an offset of 2 to get my Tuesdays, and I use a 7 (or 0) to get my Thursdays.  These will give the offset from Saturday for the 3rd of January, the 2nd of January and the 7th of January for any given year.

The numbers you use coincidentally are the same offsets (since they never cross February).  In other words, trivially, your 3rd of January falls on the same day of the week as my 3rd of January.  Likewise, my 2nd of January falls on the same day as your 3rd of October and my 7th of January will always fall on the same day of the week as your 3rd of December.

I hope that this helps you determine what you were trying to understand.

Here is what the formulas would likely be using with what I typed above:

Mondays:

```
=HVIS.FEJL(SAMMENLIGN(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;-2)-UGEDAG(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;3))+AG5*7;Året!$B$6:$B$40;0);"")
```

Tuesdays:

```
=HVIS.FEJL(SAMMENLIGN(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;-2)-UGEDAG(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;2))+AG5*7;Året!$B$6:$B$40;0);"")
```

Thursdays:

```
=HVIS.FEJL(SAMMENLIGN(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;-2)-UGEDAG(DATO(ÅR(Året!$B$2);1;7))+AG5*7;Året!$B$6:$B$40;0);"")
```

I hope this remotely responds to what you were asking.

Comment: Wednesday will be 1 then, but if I use 6 for Friday and 5 for Saturday, for the dates in weeknumber 35 (31/08/2018 and 01/09/2018) then it gives the cell for weeknumber 36 a color and not 35, why?

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with the first part of the formula, but I am stumped. I could not determine why you relate this back to the 29th of December of the prior year (and adjust from there). I suspect that this date worked for a prior year and that each year should be based on a particular day of that final week of the prior year. The rest of the formula (i.e., the parts for the Mon/Thurs/Tues) would also need to changed to work with the particular day of the last week of the prior year.

Comment: I am also having trouble understanding how weeks are structured in the lookup and how your colors are determined so perhaps if you add that information to the original post, someone can suggest a better way to achieve what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi FocusWiz
I have added a picture that shows the AG5 Weeknumber, the other weeks is then AH5 = AG5+1 and so on.

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand the issue, but see my next answer since it is far too much to type here.  Thank you for the additional information.  I now understand that you are using the Excel WEEKNUM formula and trying to make it work with the values you are computing.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that whatever description you have given regarding your problem is not well defined. What i have gather from all the discussion here is you are trying to figure out 'Monday' before 29th Dec ? is it ? if this is the stumbling block then here is the neat solution (Assuming C3 has your date as 29/Dec):

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(C3,-1,"0111111")
```

will give you the date prior to 29th Dec which is Monday...
To get Tuesday prior to 29th Dec, use this -

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(C3,-1,"1011111")
```

see in the 'weekend' part of the formula, we are saying the day (whatever day we want) is FALSE(not weekend) rest all are weekend(TRUE (1))...

Hope you will be able to build your rest of the formula from here....